# php работа с буфером не дает ожидаемого результата

Tags: php, buffer

Начал активно использовать буфер в PHP из-за необходимости формирования сложных data-параметров, точнее размещения скобок внутри скобок. Для теста создал простой скрипт. Бьюсь и не могу понять следующий момент:

А: есть php скрипт, в результате работы для $output получаю корректный html-код.

```
 $test = "Проверка";
 $tpl = "<h2>$test</h2>";
    ob_start();
    echo $tpl;
 $output = ob_get_clean();
```

Б: Если я переношу шаблон ($tpl) в отдельный ini-файл

```
tpl11 = "<h2>$test</h2>";
```

и считываю его от туда, то в $output уже не происходит замена переменной $test, а отображается лишь название переменной.

```
$test = "Проверка";
$conf = new Config(DIR_CONF ."/small_tpl.ini");
$tpl = $conf->get_param('fsi','tpl11');

ob_start();
echo $tpl;
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

Не пойму в чем дело.

Comment: А почему переменная `$test` должна быть видна в ini-файле?

Comment: Дело не в буффере, а в том что вы не совсем понимаете как работает PHP. В вашем случае наверное стоит обратить внимание на функцию eval. Ну или пересмотреть принципы работы вашего "шаблонизатора"

Comment: я считал из ini-файла строку в которой есть название переменной, затем определил ее и вывел через echo .

Comment: Честно - никогда не использовал eval в php, только в JS. Попробую, по описанию вроде как оно.

Answer (score 0):

eval помогло, не смотря на предупреждения в интернете.